# Regular expression find and select

Tags: regex, atom-editor

I am trying to select all hyphens such that I can replace them with spaces. I'm doing so to allow for better accessibility within my CMS. I am currently using atom find and replace with the Regex option.

```
<img src="http://myurl.com/images/name-of-image.jpg" title="this-is-my-title" alt="here-is-a-description-of-this-image" />
```

With regular expression, I would like to select title and alt and replace each of the hyphens with a single space.

So I was thinking to start with:

```
^(alt|title=\")[\-]*(\")$ //does not work
```

and this could be `$1` but I don't know how to select only the hyphens following this criteria. There must be a solution for this.

Comment: Please specify language, technology

Comment: Your example doesn't begin with `alt` or `title="` so there is no way `^(alt|title=\")` can match.

Answer (score 0):

### Brief

Seeing as how you haven't specified a language, I'll just assume [regex](/questions/tagged/regex) means any working regex and that you'll get it to work after. As such, this answer uses PCRE regex.

What you should instead do is get all the attributes individually and then if the attribute is in your list `["alt", "title"]`, you should simply do a string replacement to change `-` into .

---

### Code

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/8rBzcd/2)

```
(?:\b(?:alt|title)="|\G(?!\A))[^"-]*\K-
```

---

### Results

#### Input

```
<img src="http://myurl.com/images/name-of-image.jpg" title="this-is-my-title" alt="here-is-a-description-of-this-image" />
```

#### Output

```
<img src="http://myurl.com/images/name-of-image.jpg" title="this is my title" alt="here is a description of this image" />
```

---

### Explanation

- `(?:\b(?:alt|title)="|\G(?!\A))` Match either of the following

  - `\b(?:alt|title)="` Match the following

    - `\b` Assert position as a word boundary
    - `(?:alt|title)` Match either `alt` or `title` literally
    - `="` Match this literally
  - `\G(?!\A)` Assert position at the end of the previous match
- `[^"-]*?` Match any character that is not in the set (anything except `"` and `-`) any number of times
- `\K` Resets the starting point of the reported match. Any previously consumed characters are no longer included in the final match
- `-` Match the hyphen character `-` literally

Comment: Sorry guys, I failed to mention that I'm using atom's find and replace to do this. I tried using your examples and it just isn't working Atom may not know those meta characters? Thank you for your help. Sorry for being vague as to where it would be applied to as I didn't know there were specifics for it to work.

Comment: @Wallace if you download and use Notepad++ you can use my code.

Comment: @Wallace the only thing I can think of that would likely work in Atom is to use `(\b(?:alt|title)="[^"-]*)-` and replace with `$1 `. Run that multiple times (until no more replacements are made)